# Visual Studio Indentation With Method Chains & Lambdas (=>)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin-studio

I am unable to set the formatting options in Visual Studio (or Xamarin Studio) to indent nicely when using lambdas.

This is what **I want**: all the methods line up and method bodies indented

```
prop
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Where( foo => {
        // I want this tidy indentation
    })
    .Subscribe( foo => {
        // I want this tidy indentation
    })
```

This is what **I get**: the methods line up and but bodies don't

```
prop
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Where( foo => {
    // Urgh... I get this messy indentation
})
    .Subscribe( foo => {
    // Urgh... I get this messy indentation
})
```

How can I keep auto indentation and get my desired formatting?

Comment: I just tried and it behaves correctly using defaults settings in VS 2017..?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I've not got the default settings, so something is overriding it.

Comment: Resharper maybe? Go through your settings or export them, revert to defaults and compare.

Comment: I've tried with the defaults on Visual Studio For Mac... didn't work :(

Comment: As far as I'm aware, we haven't really landed on a globally accepted indentation for lambdas, they're quite recent still. I see wildly different opinions within the same company, let alone within the sector. As a general, I am opposed to egyptian brackets in C# (it's more for Javascript and CSS, in my opinion). While I don't think they are particularly horrible for your example, mixing egyptian and non-egyptian bracket styles (what if the lambda is surrounded by an if/foreach/...?) seems like it leads to more problems than it solves.

Comment: @ross, I suggest exporting all of your VS settings, then resetting to default.  If that doesn't fix it, you can restore your exported settings.  If it does... that would confirm its something in your settings?  I can't test this here, since I have resharper installed.

Comment: @Ross That is just an "issue" with VS4M, format the code via `Ctrl-i` and then manually adjust the indentation on those lines, fill out a VS4M suggestion @ https://aka.ms/vs/mac/provide-suggestion

Comment: @Ross should've mentioned you were using VS for Mac :)

Comment: @grmbl I would have but I'm using it on Mac and PC (unfortunately) I've given up for now and tried Rider. I'm happy with Riders fiormatting, which may be powered by resharpe, and feels more intuitive to me.

Comment: I'm going to close this issue as it seems I'm the only one it's not working for. Thanks for your help